# SQL Server - ALTER query can create FK relationships, but cannot view them?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-server-2012, alter

I'm stumped on whether I have written the correct syntax to create a foreign key. 
I used SQL Server 2012 Express.

If I run a ALTER query to set a foreign key relationship between two table, it works fine, no errors occured. However, if I right-click the table where the FK was created, I don't see any relationships.

This is the ALTER query I have wrote. It creates a relationship between Employers and Employees with EmployerID as a FK.

```
USE demodemo;

BEGIN TRAN t1
ALTER TABLE Employees
WITH check
ADD CONSTRAINT Employees_EmployerID_FK FOREIGN KEY 
    (EmployerID) REFERENCES Employers(ID);
GO
```

The command was executed 'successfully'.

However, if I *right click* the table, Employees, and select 'Relationships'.

No foreign keys relationships can be seen.

I thought writing the above ALTER query would be the equivalent of creating a FK relationship via the 'Relationships' gui.

Despite having no issues in creating foreign key relationships, I just cannot see them at all.

- What could I be doing wrong?
- Is my ALTER query correct?
- What is the ALTER syntax equivalent to allow me to view the "selected relationships"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DML is missing `COMMIT`. Also, right click and refresh after executing the SQL

Raj

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the COMMIT command. Just tried it and I was able to view the relationships. 

Many thanks for your help!